# What are examples of zero capacity quantum channels with Choi rank less than $d$?

Tags: quantum-operation, communication, partial-transpose, channel-capacity

All the currently known examples of quantum channels with zero quantum capacity are either *PPT* or *anti-degradable*. These notions can be conveniently defined in terms of the Choi matrix of the given channel:

1. A channel is said to be *PPT* if its Choi matrix is positive under partial transposition. In other words, the partial action of such a channel on any bipartite state results in a state which stays positive under partial transposition. Maximally entangled states cannot be distilled from such states at any positive rate, which is why these states are also called *bound* entangled. This fact can be used to show that quantum information cannot be reliably transmitted through these channels and hence these channels have zero quantum capacity.
2. A channel is said to be *anti-degradable* if its Choi matrix admits a two-copy symmetric extension. Such a channel operates on any input state to yield a combined output-environment state which is symmetric under exchange. One can use this fact to show that if these channels can be used to reliably transmit quantum information, it would lead to a violation of the no-cloning theorem. Hence, anti-degradable channels have zero quantum capacity.

The aforementioned classes of channels are really distinct in the sense that one class is not a subset of the other or vice versa. The two classes have a non-trivial intersection which is known to contain the well-know class of entanglement-breaking channels. Interested readers should refer to this wonderful [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1807) for a more thorough discussion on these concepts.

I am interested in examples of such zero capacity channels $\Phi : M_d \rightarrow M_d$ which have Choi ranks strictly less than $d$. Recall that the Choi rank of a channel is the rank of its Choi matrix which equals the minimal number of Kraus operators required in the channel's Kraus representation. For $d=2$, the rank constraint forces us to look at only unitary conjugations of the form $\Phi (\rho) = U\rho U^\dagger$, which have strictly positive capacity. For the next dimension $d=3$, all examples of zero capacity channels that I know of have Choi ranks $\geq 3$ (such as the PPT channels in the depolarizing/dephasing family or the anti-degradable amplitude damping channels). Hence the question: Are there known examples of zero capacity qutrit channels with Choi rank $=2$?

[Cross posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/619062/zero-capacity-quantum-channels)

Comment: Please mark crossposts as such.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Done!